# Excel Macro: make a recorded one less cell specifc?

Tags: vba, excel

I've recorded a simple macro that I need to make into something generic, so it can be used for any row and last four cells. Here is my recroded version:

```
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Range("Q12:T12").Select
Range("T12").Activate
Selection.Copy
```

End Sub

How do I

- make it go to the last cell of the ROW I place the cursor into?
- change the cell specific ranges into a range that just means: select this cell and 3 more to the left?

... the selection.copy I think I can nearly manage :)

Many thanks
Mike

Comment: PRO TIP: If you're using Excel for Windows, you can record your macros in RELATIVE mode instead of ABSOLUTE mode and get a recording in which all cell references are relevant to the starting selection instead of absolute.

Comment: Great tip, I'l make sure I use this next time. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will copy the last four cells in any row you click into:

```
Sub CopyLastFourCellsOfRow()
Dim lastCell As Range
Dim rngToCopy As Range

Set lastCell = Selection.End(xlToRight)
Set rngToCopy = Range(lastCell, lastCell.Offset(0, -3))

rngToCopy.Copy

End Sub
```

**Update** - If your row has broken data then best approach is to start in the final column of the spreadsheet (column IV) and then work back. To achieve this replace the `lastCell` statement with the following:

```
Set lastCell = Cells(Selection.Row, 256).End(xlToLeft)
```

Comment: Slight problem. Some of the rows have broken data, so is there a way of making it go right to the end of the ROW and then come back?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do the individual steps you're asking about all in one swift move.
To make it go to the last cell in the current row, you just use ActiveCell.End(xlToRight). (Use 'ActiveCell' because it is equivalent to 'Selection' when only one cell is selected, but works even if multiple cells are selected.)

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)).Select
```

will select the current cell and 3 more to the left. Note that you do not need to do "Selection.Copy" in a separate step. You can simply go:

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)).Copy
```

Comment: Exactly the type of response I was hoping for - an answer with education included. Many thanks.